# C# -- should we should cast for get in Indexer Method

Tags: c#

```
public class PeopleCollection : IEnumerable
{
    private Dictionary<string, Person> listPeople = new Dictionary<string, Person>();

    // This indexer returns a person based on a string index.
    public Person this[string name]
    {
        get { 
            return (Person)listPeople[name]; // **Is this cast necessary?**
        }
        set { 
            listPeople[name] = value; 
        }
    }
    ..
}
```

Question: should we cast the return value from `listPeople[name]` to `Person`?

Thank you

Comment: It's already explicitly cast as Person in the dictionary declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not needed. In `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` the indexer is declared as:

```
public TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
```

For the `Dictionary<string, Person>` in the `listPeople` field, `TValue` is replaced with `Person`, so the indexer will return a reference to a `Person` object.

Answer (score 2):

No, that cast isn't necessary. [Dictionary's indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) is already strongly typed to return `Person` (because that's what `TValue` is for that dictionary). That's one of the benefits of generics :)

Of course, the simplest way to find this out would be to remove the cast and see - if the Dictionary indexer *hadn't* been strongly typed, your code would have failed to compile as you'd have been trying to return `object` (or whatever) for an indexer of type `Person`.

Comment: Just got your C# In Depth book!! and glad to see you show up here:)

Comment: @q0987: Excellent - hope you enjoy it :)

Answer (score 1):

No this is not necessary but you would have found out if you removed the (Person) and compiled it.